# TCPListener missing from System.Net.Sockets namespace

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm using TCPListener which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) page should be in System.Net.Sockets, I have

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
TCPListener tcpListener = new TCPListener(10);
```

Visual Studio is producing the following error

> Error 1   The type or namespace name
>   'TCPListener' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly
>   reference?)   C:\path\WindowsService.cs   85  13  Windows
>   Service Test1

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to spell it correctly: it's `TcpListener`, not `TCPListener`. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Use intellisense, if not intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

It's case sensitive, i.e. TcpListener

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
...
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(10);
```

C# is case sensitive and the TCP section should be Tcp.

HTH

OneSHOT